# problem running tgif in ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04, fonts

I have installed **tgif** via **synaptic package manager** in Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. When I tried to run `tgif` from the terminal I got the following error message:

```
"Fatal Error in OpenFont(): Cannot open the Default(Msg)Font '-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1'.
Tgif aborted.
```

Please let me know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue too. I `apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi x11-utils texlive-latex-base`, reboot, then this issue was gone. Hope it helps in your case.

Comment: This made my tgif in 12.04 work, too. I wonder whether there is no better way than to reboot. A `sudo fc-cache -f -v` did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,
but easily recovered with `sudo apt-get install gsfonts-x11` as

```
$ sudo apt-get install tgif
$ tgif foo.obj
Fatal Error in OpenFont(): Cannot open the Default(Msg)Font '-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1'.
$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi   # may be installed by default
$ sudo apt-get install gsfonts-x11    # important
$ xset fp rehash                      # do not need reboot
$ tgif foo.obj                        # OK!
```

See http://bourbon.usc.edu/tgif/faq/systems.html .

Comment: Sorry mistakenly down voted your answer please edit so I can upvote, apologies...